# dpkg: error processing matlab-support (--configure)

Tags: 12.04, apt, upgrade, dpkg, matlab

I upgraded from Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04 in my laptop. During the process I got an error message regarding the installation of following packages:

`dynare-common`, `dynare`, `matlab-support` and `dynare-matlab`

Now when I run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get the following errors

```
Setting up matlab-support (0.0.17) ...
No default Matlab path found. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing matlab-support (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dynare-matlab:
 dynare-matlab depends on matlab-support; however:
  Package matlab-support is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing dynare-matlab (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 matlab-support
 dynare-matlab
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this error message?

P.S. how is it possible to get **Matlab** `Activation Key or License Number` for its installation?

Comment: Did you try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?

Comment: @Ron It goes to the package configuration with the following content: `The MATLAB interface needs to know where MATLAB is installed on this system. This can be specified as a single directory or, in  case of multiple MATLAB installations, as a glob expression (any expression supported by bash, including extended pattern   matching operators).                                                                                                               If, for example, the MATLAB executable is installed in /opt/matlab76/bin/matlab, please enter "/opt/matlab76".

Comment: @Ron while I can not find any matlab on my system. what can I do?

Comment: Seems to be a [new bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dynare/+bug/1580761). :( I suggest you log in there and select "this bug affects me", in order to raise its status and get a fix. In the mean time, why don't you try with an older version of dynare?

Answer (score 0):

it helped me `sudo apt-get remove matlab-support` you can try it

Comment: It would be best to expand this answer to explain *why* you think this will help the OP.  Please [edit] to expand this answer; answers without sufficient detail are subject to deletion.